# Loop through each element ID and animate

Tags: jquery

As part of an eCommerce template there will be a random number of products listed, I have iterated through each of the products and attached an ID to each of these within the product grid.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".product").each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr('id', "product" + (i + 1));
    });
});
```

I have a hover action, so when hovered over the element, it animates.

```
$('#product').hover(function(){
    $("#product-detail").animate({ "height": '0' + 'px' }, 200);
}, function(){
    $("#product-detail").animate({ "height": '74' + 'px' }, 200);
});
```

As there will always be an unknown amount of products on this list, I'm trying to iterate through each of the ID's given and animate each one on hover with the above functions but struggling to find the right approach to this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The real problem**

Based on the code you've provided, it looks like you may have misunderstanding of element ID's vs classes. At first you set your elements to have an ID of `product1`, `product2`, ..., but then you try to select the element as if it's ID were simply `product`, and then you attempt to animate a seperate element with id of `product-detail`.

If you need to deal with an unknown amount of elements on a page, use classes. There's no need to assign everything unique ID's and it will just make it more difficult when wiring up event handlers. You can uniquely identify the elements based on `this` in combination with a class selector.

**To fix your code**

First off, in your second block of code your selector is only going to work with elements of ID `product`, you need to change this to a class selector (`.product`).

Now your selector for hover should begin to fire on all `product` elements. Since you will be using a class selector for this, every element with class `product` will trigger your code. Since you only want to add the hover effect to the element which is being hovered, you can obtain a reference to that element by using `this`.

Having said all of that, I think you could accomplish the same goal without using any javascript at all, CSS already has mechanism's in place for hover and animation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However product-detail is a child of product, and that is the element that is being animated once product is being hovered over. I have updated my code to classes not ID's, now the problem being that every single element animates when I hover over one element and not individual to each. I have considered using CSS animations but for my particular case it needs to be in Javascript.

Comment: Since you said you had an unknown amount of products, I would assume you also have an unknown amount of product details, so why is this using ID? If you need reference to the child product-detail, you can do that by using `this` in combination with jquery `find()`. You just need to change your second block of code to use `$(this)` instead of `$("#product-detail")`. If the product-detail is a child of product, you should be able to find it with jQuery's `.find()` as this will traverse down the DOM to locate your `.product-detail`.